# How to make overflow-ed SVG content viewable via scrolling?

Tags: css, html, svg, scroll, overflow

I have this simple HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <embed src="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="border:3px solid green;width:200px;height:200px;overflow:scroll;">
  </body>
</html>
```

And a simple SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border:3px solid red;width:500px;height:500px;overflow:auto;">
  <circle cx="50" cy="250" r="80" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

The output from browsers:

1. [1,1] Edge: OK
2. [2,1] IE11: OK
3. [1,2] Chrome55: Not scrollable
4. [2,2] Firefox50: Scrollable at a negligible degree

[image: SVG Overflow]

How to ensure Firefox and Chrome able to have scrollable `<embed>` with overflow-ed SVG content, as in Edge and IE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put a div around the embed und use that as scrolling area...

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div style="border:3px solid green;width:100px;height:100px;overflow:scroll;">
    <embed src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/SVG-Grundelemente.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

to match the behaviour of MS browsers, you have to extend your viewBox to contain all elements you want to be able to scroll to...
given the appropiate width and height should do want you want then...

You can as well roll your own zoom and pan solution using svgDocuments `currentTranslate` and `currentScale` properties... I would be curious how currentTranslate behaves for this weird MS behaviour...

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tried your method in Chrome with my example in question, but I'm not able to scroll to view the whole circle as what we have in Edge and IE, instead I'm only getting the SVG content as in the Chrome example in question, with the circle clipped, and scrollable since the container div is smaller.

Comment: The snippet works just fine. But it is only scrollable div with overflow-ed SVG. To clarify, I seeking solution for scrollable SVG with overflow-ed SVG content, e.g. <g>, <rect> and etc.

Comment: For example, in your posted case, make the dimensions of div and SVG (embed) the same, e.g. 500px x 500px. Then, position the SVG element within absolutely and exceeding the dimension of container to see if overflow/scrolling is working.

Comment: SVG is an "infinite" canvas, so scrolling outside of your explicitly set viewport isn't such a good idea (by Microsoft)... 
Zoom and Pan handling on the other hand is by spec a concern of the client. So from that perspective its perfectly fine to do this.

If you want to replicate the behaviour of MS browsers, use the construct i posted above, and change your viewBox to contain everything that should be scrollable to.

update my answer accordingly...